# How to use a macro in another workbook without open the source code of this macro

Tags: vba, excel

I developed a macro in a specific worksheet (for example: worksheet 1), but I want to run this macro in another worksheet (worksheet 2) without having to open the source code (worksheet 1).

Is there any way to call it?

Regards,

Comment: Have you tried simply typing the name of the other code? If the name in sheet 1 is `Sub Test`, in sheet 2's code, type `Test` or `Call Test(Variables)`. If it's a `Private Sub`, you can type `Call Sheet.Test`

Comment: the sequence: 
1- open the worksheet 1;
2- access the macro tab and see/use the codes of other sheet 2 without open it.

Comment: By Macro Tab, do you mean the same thing as `Alt+F8`? If that is what you are talking about, go to your modules and make sure they are not showing `Private Sub`, you can change to `Public Sub` or just `Sub`.

Comment: they are not private sub, but to see macro do I have necessary to open the source code? is there any way to select a folder to read all macros  in different sheets?

Comment: How do you want to "See" the macros? By "See", do you just mean "Run"? Are you wanting to "Run" all macros at the same time? If you want to see a list of them that you can run individually, you can [create a UserForm](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html) and add buttons that will call each macro if that's what you want. I am just not really understanding what exactly you are asking for.

Comment: Let me try to explain, I want to use/run a macro in the workbook 1 and I developed this macro in workbook 2, but I don't want to open the workbook 2.

Comment: Makes a little more sense, because your original question said nothing about two different books. All it was asking for was about the macro was located in different worksheets. Why don't you [edit your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46621332/edit) and clarify that for the other readers, because that's quite a big detail to leave out.

Comment: already changed it ;)

Comment: Your question is talking about two different **worksheets** but your title and a comment to an answer implies that your are talking about different **workbooks**.  Please edit your question to make it clearer what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run VBA code located in a *Closed* workbook. However, you can still run code from another workbook that is currently **open**. You can use VBA code in your current workbook that can automatically open the other workbook, run the code, then close the workbook.

So to open a workbook, `Workbooks.Open`. To run the macro in that workbook, you will need to use `Application.Run "FileName.xlsm!YourMacroNameHere"`.

There is one thing you will need to be aware of when running code from another workbook. If the code makes references to that workbook only, then your code will not make changes in the new workbook.

Example:

If the code you are using says things such as `Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets()`, then anything that references `Ws` will not update the book that called it (hence, it will not reference the book with the code `Application.Run`)

Comment: Oh Thanks! that is what I wanted, really apprecciate it!

Comment: Hello, what can i do to avoid ThisWorkbook.Worksheets() ? I have it in my macro, how can I set it to the right workbook ?

Answer (score 0):

Although the approved answer is correct, there is also such a thing as the "Personal Macro Workbook". You can find this workbook when trying to record a new macro, in the "store macro in" dialog. This workbook is available across all your workbooks and does not need to be opened for your macros to run.

[image: Personal macro workbook screenshot]